# To pass parameter to bash script file

Tags: bash

I want to pass the version tag argument like v1.3 to bash script file. I shown my file which contains tag argument. I want to pass v1.3 argument to `${tag}` from terminal. This tag value often changed. Can any one tell me how to pass the argument for below bash script file.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/file
git checkout -- .
git checkout tags/${tag}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use what are known as "positional parameters", `$1`, `$2` and so on.

eg

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/file
git checkout -- .
git checkout tags/"$1"
```

Now you can do `myscript tag`  or `myscript anothertag`  or  `myscript test` and the value of `$1` will be what you enter.

Answer (score 2):

Your script could be made to work the way you inted by the addition of a single line:

```
#!/bin/bash
tag=$1
cd /path/to/file
git checkout -- .
git checkout tags/${tag}
```

This would take the first command line argument of the script an assign it to the variable `tag`.

To allow for spaces in the value of `$tag`, double quote the variable expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
tag=$1
cd /path/to/file
git checkout -- .
git checkout tags/"$tag"
```

To only do the `git` operations if the `cd` succeeded, make each command depend on the successful completion of the previous command:

```
#!/bin/bash
tag=$1
cd /path/to/file &&
git checkout -- . &&
git checkout tags/"$tag"
```

alternatively, make the script automatically terminate when one of the commands fail,

```
#!/bin/bash -e
tag=$1
cd /path/to/file
git checkout -- .
git checkout tags/"$tag"
```

Since this script is not using anything that is `bash`-specific, it will easily run under `/bin/sh` instead:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

tag=$1

cd /path/to/file
git checkout -- .
git checkout tags/"$tag"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameters to your script with positional  parameters

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/file
TAG=$1  # read the first paramater passed to your script like ./myscript v1.2
if [ "$TAG" != "" ]; then
    git checkout -- .
    git checkout tags/"$TAG"
else
    echo "Please enter a Tag "
    exit 1 ;
fi
```

you can also use interactive mode to allow user to enter value to your script like .

```
   #!/bin/bash
    read -p "Please enter tag: " TAG
     cd /path/to/file
    if [ -n "$TAG" ]; then
        git checkout -- .
        git checkout tags/"$TAG"
    else
        echo "Please run again and enter a Tag "
        exit 1 ;
    fi
```